# Magento 2 - adding external JS/CSS with parameters in the URL

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add references to external JS/CSS files, and for the most of them, all works fine. However as soon as I try and add an external script with parameters in the URL (for example `&sensor=false&libraries=geometry`), it seems to cause issues. In my case, it's causing Google maps not to detect the API key. I tried replacing the `&` with `%26`, but this didn't work.

Adding the script directly into the template works, just not through the XML, which is what I need in this case.

### XML

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" src_type="url"/>
        <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&sensor=false&libraries=geometry" src_type="url"/>
     </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get around this by creating a block referencing a separate phtml file and adding the scripts there instead. Bit of a faff, but works. Other suggestions welcome!

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="frontuser" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/scripts.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```